# ESP32: Can't start Serial Bluetooth after creating FreeRTOS task handlers or vice versa, can't create the task handlers after initializing Bluetooth

Tags: esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

Well, I'm just starting with FreeRTOS, tried reading the docs but not getting much help. I'm using:

- PlatformIO
- ESP32 Dev Module

The task handlers run voice command detection from Atomic14's implementation of Tensorflow's micro-speech example.

1. If Serial Bluetooth is initialized first, it works but the voice
   command detection doesn't as Guru Meditation Errors are thrown.
2. If the voice command detection task
   handlers are created first, Serial Bluetooth fails to start.

The code compiles and uploads to the board with no errors. But when the board restarts, the errors are thrown.

**If the task handers are created first, Serial BT throws the error below:**

```
[E][BluetoothSerial.cpp:538] _init_bt(): initialize bluedroid failed
```

**If Serial BT is initialized first, the task handlers throw the error below:**

```
-------> Loaded Voice Prefs!
Created Neral Net
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d62aa  PS      : 0x00060030  A0      : 0x800d5dbc  A1      : 0x3ffdc0e0  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3fe00000  A4      : 0x00000140  A5      : 0x00000140  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x800d62aa  A9      : 0x3ffdc0d0  
A10     : 0x37ca20bd  A11     : 0x3ef94417  A12     : 0x21700000  A13     : 0x37ca20bd  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400029ac  LEND    : 0x400029cb  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400d62aa:0x3ffdc0e0 0x400d5db9:0x3ffdc110 0x400d1c52:0x3ffdc140 0x400d2f61:0x3ffdc160 0x400dafee:0x3ffdc1b0 0x40090a72:0x3ffdc1d0

Rebooting...
␇P�␌��
�ڔ␙␙␒�␀!�-------> Loaded Voice Prefs!
Created Neral Net
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d62aa  PS      : 0x00060030  A0      : 0x800d5dbc  A1      : 0x3ffdc0e0  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3fe00000  A4      : 0x00000140  A5      : 0x00000140  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x800d62aa  A9      : 0x3ffdc0d0  
A10     : 0x37ca20bd  A11     : 0x3ef94417  A12     : 0x21700000  A13     : 0x37ca20bd  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400029ac  LEND    : 0x400029cb  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400d62aa:0x3ffdc0e0 0x400d5db9:0x3ffdc110 0x400d1c52:0x3ffdc140 0x400d2f61:0x3ffdc160 0x400dafee:0x3ffdc1b0 0x40090a72:0x3ffdc1d0

Rebooting...
```

**Main.cpp Setup**

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Ticker.h>
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <Preferences.h>
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <driver/i2s.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "I2SMicSampler.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "CommandDetector.h"
#include "CommandProcessor.h"
#include "patterns.h"
#include "switchcase.h"
#include "voice.h"
#include "remote.h"

#define NUM_LEDS 75
#define DATA_PIN 16
// FASTLED no of leds on the strip
CRGB led[NUM_LEDS];

// IR init. Don't connect to spi pin
IRrecv irrecv(4);
// decode_results results; // IR init

// Prefs instance
Preferences preferences;

// This ticker will check for command changes in the backgound
// from BT, IR and Voice
Ticker updater;

// Bluetooth Serial object
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

// Handle received and sent commands
String command = "p1201";
String command2 = "p1101";
String brightness = "b255";
bool useVoice = true;
bool useColorsList = true;

void receiveIRCode()
{
  decode_results results;
  // IR reciever code goes here
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);

    for (int c = 0; c < 17; c++)
    {
      if (IRCodes[c] == results.value)
      {
        switchIR(results.value);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// If new color or pattern command is received, make the change
void makeChange()
{
  Serial.println("--------> Making Change");
  Serial.println(command2);
  //------- Change Color
  if ((command.startsWith("0", 0)) & (command.length() == 8))
  {
    long color = strtol(command.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    hexToRGB(command);
    fill_solid(led, NUM_LEDS, color);
    FastLED.show();
  }
  //------- Change Pattern
  if ((command.startsWith("p", 0)) & (command.length() == 5))
  {
    switchPatterns(command.substring(1).toInt());
  }
  //------- Change Voice Assignments
  if (command2.startsWith("v"))
  {
    changeVoiceAssignment();
  }
  //------- Change Use Voice Status
  if (command2.startsWith("u"))
  {
    useVoiceStatus();
  }
}

// Check if a new command has been received
void checkChange()
{
  // IR reciever code goes here
  receiveIRCode();
  // Voice detection code goes here
  if (useVoice)
  {
    Serial.println("Checking voice...");
  }
  // BT control code goes here
  if (SerialBT.available())
  {
    command2 = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (!command2.equals(command))
    {
      Serial.println("-------->CHANGES! New command is: " + command2);
    }
  }
}

// Change brightness
void changeBrightness()
{
  brightness = command2;
  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness.substring(1).toInt());
  FastLED.show();
  Serial.println("-------> Set new brightness");
  command2 = command;
  preferences.begin("esp", false);
  preferences.putString("bright", brightness);
  preferences.end();
}

// Change brightness
void changeColor(int c)
{
  if (c == 1)
    fill_solid(led, NUM_LEDS, 0xff0000);
  if (c == 2)
    fill_solid(led, NUM_LEDS, 0x00ff00);
  if (c == 3)
    fill_solid(led, NUM_LEDS, 0x0000ff);
  if (c == 4)
    fill_solid(led, NUM_LEDS, 0xffff00);
  FastLED.show();
}

// i2s config for reading from both channels of I2S
i2s_config_t i2sMemsConfigBothChannels = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX),
    .sample_rate = 16000,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_32BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_MIC_CHANNEL,
    .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S),
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
    .dma_buf_count = 4,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = false,
    .fixed_mclk = 0};

// i2s microphone pins
i2s_pin_config_t i2s_mic_pins = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_MIC_SERIAL_CLOCK,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_MIC_LEFT_RIGHT_CLOCK,
    .data_out_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE,
    .data_in_num = I2S_MIC_SERIAL_DATA};

// This task does all the heavy lifting for our application
void applicationTask(void *param)
{
  disableCore0WDT();

  CommandDetector *commandDetector = static_cast<CommandDetector *>(param);

  const TickType_t xMaxBlockTime = pdMS_TO_TICKS(100);
  while (true)
  {
    // wait for some audio samples to arrive
    uint32_t ulNotificationValue = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, xMaxBlockTime);
    if (ulNotificationValue > 0)
    {
      commandDetector->run();
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Getting Preferences
  preferences.begin("esp", false);
  command2 = preferences.getString("command2", "p1101");
  brightness = preferences.getString("bright", "b255");
  useVoice = preferences.getBool("useVoice", true);
  useColorsList = preferences.getBool("useColorsList", true);
  hexToRGB(preferences.getString("color", "0xffffff"));
  loadVoiceAssignments();
  preferences.end();
  // Serial.println("Command2:  " + command2);
  // Fastled initialization and settings
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(led, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness.substring(1).toInt());

  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the IR receiver

  SerialBT.begin("Bonga Lamp A01");

  // make sure we don't get killed for our long running tasks
  esp_task_wdt_init(10, false);

  // Direct i2s input from INMP441
  I2SSampler *i2s_sampler = new I2SMicSampler(i2s_mic_pins, false);

  // the command processor
  CommandProcessor *command_processor = new CommandProcessor();

  // create our application
  CommandDetector *commandDetector = new CommandDetector(i2s_sampler, command_processor);

  // set up the i2s sample writer task
  TaskHandle_t applicationTaskHandle;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(applicationTask, "Command Detect", 8192, commandDetector, 1, &applicationTaskHandle, 0);
  Serial.println("---- 1");
  Serial.println("--------");

  // portENABLE_INTERRUPTS();
  // start sampling from i2s device - use I2S_NUM_0 as that's the one that supports the internal ADC
  i2s_sampler->start(I2S_NUM_0, i2sMemsConfigBothChannels, applicationTaskHandle);
  Serial.println("---- 2");
  Serial.println("--------");

  // Bluetooth device name
  
  // Serial.println("Bluetooth Ready for pairing!");
  // Serial.println("---- 3");
  // Serial.println("--------");

  updater.attach_ms(100, checkChange);
  Serial.println("---- 4");
  Serial.println("--------");
}

void loop()
{
  // If command received is different from previous command, change color or pattern
  if (!command2.equals(command) & !command2.startsWith("b"))
  {
    command = command2;
    preferences.begin("esp", false);
    preferences.putString("command2", command2);
    if (command2.startsWith("0", 0))
    {
      preferences.putString("color", command2);
      preferences.end();
    }
    preferences.end();
    makeChange();
  }
  // If it is a brightness change command
  else if (command2.startsWith("b"))
  {
    changeBrightness();
  }
}
```

Please help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Duncan Mwanik. There's a tool called the [ESP Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) which will give you a stack backtrace based on the information the ESP outputs on a crash.  This can be very helpful in understanding what's going on. Also, have you checked how much memory is available (`ESP.getFreeHeap()`, `ESP. getMaxAllocHeap()`) when your code is having issues? For instance, when SerialBT fails? Between Bluetooth, FastLED and voice recognition you may be out of memory.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that and see. I'll also check the memory.